# Overleaf error: "LaTeX Error: File `size0.clo' not found"

Tags: errors, compilation-error

When insering the following code in overleaf:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,extsizes,moresize,background,lipsum}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=1,color=black,angle=0,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Screenshot.jpg}}}

\newcommand\DeactivateBG{\backgroundsetup{contents={}}}

\newcommand\ActivateBG{\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=\papewidth,height=\paperheight]{Screenshot.jpg}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\ActivateBG

\begin{centering}
\Huge
Title

\end{centering}

\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

no document is produced and I get the following error message:
[image]Can somebody please help? Thanks.(The Screenshot.jpg file has been uploaded to overleaf)(The file is produced using lualatex)

Comment: you must load `extsizes` with a size option. e.g. `\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}`, but as the log says it is better to use the extarticle class instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now I get a pdf file having the Title set as expected but the background image is missing. Is there anything additional that can be done?

Comment: sorry but the background is quite unrelated to the title of your question. So better ask a new question. And use an image everyone has, e.g. `\includegraphics{example-image}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer okay, I am uploading it as a new question. Thank you very much for your help! (If you are interested to the new question, link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/653325/problem-inserting-background-image-in-lualatex-using-overleaf )