# Problem inserting background image in lualatex using overleaf

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor,moresize,background,lipsum}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\backgroundsetup{scale=1,opacity=0.5,color=black,angle=0,contents={\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{Screenshot.jpg}}}

\newcommand\DeactivateBG{\backgroundsetup{contents={}}}

\newcommand\ActivateBG{\backgroundsetup{contents={\includegraphics[width=\papewidth,height=\paperheight]{Screenshot.jpg}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\ActivateBG

\begin{centering}
\Huge
\textcolor{blue}{
Title}

\end{centering}

\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

and I get the following result:
[image]
What am I doing wrong and I cannot insert my background image successfully? (Screenshot.jpg has been uploaded successfully to overleaf) Thanks.

Comment: It should be `\paperwidth`, not `\papewidth`. Other than that, I cannot see any errors in your code. I only wonder why you use `\backgroundsetup` to set up a default background and then overwrite it with your custom command. Check the paths of both, the image as well as the file where it is included.

Comment: @JasperHabicht You are right. Thanks for noticing!